# c# How to create BaloonTip Accesible in any place of code

Tags: c#, .net-2.0

**EDIT**

I will change my question - how to make a baloonTip that could be accesible from any place in code. No matter what class or loaded dll?

Comment: `ex`'s stacktrace should provide a good starting point of where to look.

Comment: What do you mean "stacktrace" ?

Comment: The `StackTrace` property of your exception. Try changing the MessageBox in your exception handler to display `ex.StackTrace` instead of `ex.Message`, and please post the result as an edit to your question.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't understand the question? Did you tried Tooltip control?

Comment: Put a static Tooltip control in a public static class, add the relevant using directive and you're good to go

Comment: Alex -> now i have main class SysTrayApp that has NotifyIcon, TrayMenu and my main form variables. Should i place notifyicon someqhere else?

Answer (score 0):

I Found the solution.
The most easy way is to send a pointer of trayicon variable through constructors. In all classes. Sending a pointer needs to add ref before type of war. For example
    MyClass(ref Notifyicon try){...}
and creating wariable would be
    new MyClass(ref trayicon);